# Dynamic Generics Java

Tags: java, generics

What I want: I want to specify a list of parameters and then return a list of those types specifically returning the type in the index it was set in.

Dynamic generics like you specify x y z in one method get X Y Z in another method dynamic amount of generic parameters using the same class.

Like for my command API, if I have `Command<File>` or `Command<Object>`, I want to specify `Command<File, Long>` or `Command<X,Y,Z...>`

```
public abstract <X, Y, Z> getParams(String... args);
public abstract void run(X x, Y y, Z z);
```

Or something like that where xyz could be in a list or actually out of the list.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Generics are a static, compile-time only feature, so "dynamic generics" sounds like you're looking for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I want it so it automatically typecasts it the point of generics. I want to specify classes in which the params are in and then have it create a methods based on those generic keys and it will be like File,Long or File instead of just single object each time

Comment: So, you want generics with a variable number of type parameters? Java does not support that.

Comment: what If I wrapped everything in a list and use a getter and then checked each index which you input into it somehow it returned the exact same thing typecasted

Answer (score 1):

In Java, dynamic generics even just for the source to throw compile errors is not supported at least in Java 8. Who knows in Java 15.

The next best thing is to wrap your parameters into a class and make a getter method. When receiving the wrong class it should throw a class cast exception.

```
public class ParamList<T> {
    
    public T[] args;
    public ParamList(T[] args)
    {
        this.args = args;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <K extends Object> K get(int index)
    {
        return (K) this.args[index];
    }

}
```

Comment: `K extends Object`? That seems redundant to me.

Comment: no because K equals whatever the outside command object needs. If it doesn't match T it will throw a class cast exception while still being super simple to use and no class cast exceptions. Working as intended

Comment: Yes, but it also works when you remove the upper bound `Object`, since all objects implicitly extend `Object` class. Just `<K>` is sufficient.